# How to resolve ggplotly error using color fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Using the `ggplotly` call extending from ggplot2, I'm trying to add an outline to the points.

The call to `ggplot` works, but extending the call to `ggplotly` yields an error.

> The objective is the have an interactive plot with color filled points based on a continuous variable with a black outline (using `pch`=21 in this case).

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=hp))+geom_point(pch=I(21))+scale_fill_continuous(low='red', high='blue')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=hp))+geom_point(pch=I(21))+scale_fill_continuous(low='red', high='blue')+ggplotly()
```

`Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
In addition: Warning message:
In L$marker$color[idx] <- aes2plotly(data, params, "fill")[idx] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but instead of tagging on `+ggplotly()` on the end of the `ggplot()` call, you need to surround the `ggplot` with `ggplotly`

```
## save the ggplot object 
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=hp))+
    geom_point(pch=I(21))+
    scale_fill_continuous(low='red', high='blue')

## call ggplotly on the ggplot object
ggplotly(g)
```

Although, I am noticing that the `fill` isn't respected when calling `ggplotly`...

To do this directly in `plot_ly`, you can specify a colour palette and plot it

```
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(length(unique(mtcars$hp)))

plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, color = ~hp, colors = pal, 
            type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
            marker = list(size = 10,
                          line = list(color = "black",
                          width = 2)))
```

See [here](http://moderndata.plot.ly/create-colorful-graphs-in-r-with-rcolorbrewer-and-plotly/) and [here](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/) for more examples

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as you've noticed the output doesn't show the fill color properly (it's all red) and the error message still there...

Comment: Me either!  Is it possible to add fills based on factors using base plotly?

Comment: Looking better.  Can you get the points to have a black outline?

Comment: At the risk of polluting the comments, nice!