# How to keep the format of plot generated by ggplot while converting to plotly by ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, plotly

Assuming generating a scatter plot with `ggplot` which has the gradient color and shape based on the variables in `mtcars` built-in database in `R` .

using the following script adopted from [Nathan Day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5878751/nathan-day) in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594211/how-to-place-a-border-around-points-for-the-scatter-plot-with-gradient-color-and):

```
library(ggplot2)


 plot<-  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, fill = cyl, size = cyl)) +
        geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 2) +  
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7)) +
        scale_size(range = c(2,6))
```

we would get the following plot 
[image]

Now, when I am trying to convert it to `ploty` using the following script :

```
library(plotly)
ggploty (plot)
```

I would get the following plot which is basically change the color and I loose my **gradient colour** featur in my `ggplot` as can be seen in previous plot generated by `ggplot`.

[image]

*Of course I would get the interactive image BUT I was not able to upload in this page so I just take a static image of the generated `ploty` image.*

Can you please help me to know how I can keep the original format of `ggplot` when converting to `ploty` by `ggploty` command?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155348/how-to-resolve-ggplotly-error-using-color-fill) might help you

Comment: @HubertL Thanks a lot Buddy. It was really helpful and I figured it out how to do this.